# Headless you popover does not work on clicking in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, headless-ui

I am using the following example, which i took from here:
https://headlessui.dev/react/popover

But when i click on the solutions button, it just shows up for some milliseconds. What am i doing wrong?

```
import { Popover, Transition } from '@headlessui/react'
import { ChevronDownIcon } from '@heroicons/react/solid'
import { Fragment } from 'react'

const solutions = [
  {
    name: 'Insights',
    description: 'Measure actions your users take',
    href: '##',
    icon: IconOne,
  },
  {
    name: 'Automations',
    description: 'Create your own targeted content',
    href: '##',
    icon: IconTwo,
  },
  {
    name: 'Reports',
    description: 'Keep track of your growth',
    href: '##',
    icon: IconThree,
  },
]

export default function Example() {
  return (
    <div className="w-full max-w-sm px-4 fixed top-16">
      <Popover className="relative">
        {({ open }) => (
          <>
            <Popover.Button
              className={`
                ${open ? '' : 'text-opacity-90'}
                text-white group bg-orange-700 px-3 py-2 rounded-md inline-flex items-center text-base font-medium hover:text-opacity-100 focus:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-white focus-visible:ring-opacity-75`}
            >
              <span>Solutions</span>
              <ChevronDownIcon
                className={`${open ? '' : 'text-opacity-70'}
                  ml-2 h-5 w-5 text-orange-300 group-hover:text-opacity-80 transition ease-in-out duration-150`}
                aria-hidden="true"
              />
            </Popover.Button>
            <Transition
              as={Fragment}
              enter="transition ease-out duration-200"
              enterFrom="opacity-0 translate-y-1"
              enterTo="opacity-100 translate-y-0"
              leave="transition ease-in duration-150"
              leaveFrom="opacity-100 translate-y-0"
              leaveTo="opacity-0 translate-y-1"
            >
              <Popover.Panel className="absolute z-10 w-screen max-w-sm px-4 mt-3 transform -translate-x-1/2 left-1/2 sm:px-0 lg:max-w-3xl">
                <div className="overflow-hidden rounded-lg shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5">
                  <div className="relative grid gap-8 bg-white p-7 lg:grid-cols-2">
                    {solutions.map((item) => (
                      <a
                        key={item.name}
                        href={item.href}
                        className="flex items-center p-2 -m-3 transition duration-150 ease-in-out rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus-visible:ring focus-visible:ring-orange-500 focus-visible:ring-opacity-50"
                      >
                        <div className="flex items-center justify-center flex-shrink-0 w-10 h-10 text-white sm:h-12 sm:w-12">
                          <item.icon aria-hidden="true" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="ml-4">
                          <p className="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">
                            {item.name}
                          </p>
                          <p className="text-sm text-gray-500">
                            {item.description}
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      </a>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                  <div className="p-4 bg-gray-50">
                    <a
                      href="##"
                      className="flow-root px-2 py-2 transition duration-150 ease-in-out rounded-md hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus-visible:ring focus-visible:ring-orange-500 focus-visible:ring-opacity-50"
                    >
                      <span className="flex items-center">
                        <span className="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900">
                          Documentation
                        </span>
                      </span>
                      <span className="block text-sm text-gray-500">
                        Start integrating products and tools
                      </span>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Popover.Panel>
            </Transition>
          </>
        )}
      </Popover>
    </div>
  )
}

function IconOne() {
  return (
    <svg
      width="48"
      height="48"
      viewBox="0 0 48 48"
      fill="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <rect width="48" height="48" rx="8" fill="#FFEDD5" />
      <path
        d="M24 11L35.2583 17.5V30.5L24 37L12.7417 30.5V17.5L24 11Z"
        stroke="#FB923C"
        strokeWidth="2"
      />
      <path
        fillRule="evenodd"
        clipRule="evenodd"
        d="M16.7417 19.8094V28.1906L24 32.3812L31.2584 28.1906V19.8094L24 15.6188L16.7417 19.8094Z"
        stroke="#FDBA74"
        strokeWidth="2"
      />
      <path
        fillRule="evenodd"
        clipRule="evenodd"
        d="M20.7417 22.1196V25.882L24 27.7632L27.2584 25.882V22.1196L24 20.2384L20.7417 22.1196Z"
        stroke="#FDBA74"
        strokeWidth="2"
      />
    </svg>
  )
}

function IconTwo() {
  return (
    <svg
      width="48"
      height="48"
      viewBox="0 0 48 48"
      fill="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <rect width="48" height="48" rx="8" fill="#FFEDD5" />
      <path
        d="M28.0413 20L23.9998 13L19.9585 20M32.0828 27.0001L36.1242 34H28.0415M19.9585 34H11.8755L15.9171 27"
        stroke="#FB923C"
        strokeWidth="2"
      />
      <path
        fillRule="evenodd"
        clipRule="evenodd"
        d="M18.804 30H29.1963L24.0001 21L18.804 30Z"
        stroke="#FDBA74"
        strokeWidth="2"
      />
    </svg>
  )
}

function IconThree() {
  return (
    <svg
      width="48"
      height="48"
      viewBox="0 0 48 48"
      fill="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <rect width="48" height="48" rx="8" fill="#FFEDD5" />
      <rect x="13" y="32" width="2" height="4" fill="#FDBA74" />
      <rect x="17" y="28" width="2" height="8" fill="#FDBA74" />
      <rect x="21" y="24" width="2" height="12" fill="#FDBA74" />
      <rect x="25" y="20" width="2" height="16" fill="#FDBA74" />
      <rect x="29" y="16" width="2" height="20" fill="#FB923C" />
      <rect x="33" y="12" width="2" height="24" fill="#FB923C" />
    </svg>
  )
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a compatibility issue with React 18.
You can use the insiders build to make it work.

Uninstall the `Headless UI` package in your project and instead of `npm install @headlessui/react` do `npm install @headlessui/react@insiders` .

Or downgrade to React 17, or wait for it to get fixed.

https://github.com/tailwindlabs/headlessui#installing-the-insiders-version